# Get download headers with google-cloud-storage Python client?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

How can I get the headers (specifically `content-length`, `etag`, `content-type`, and `last-modified`) for a Google Cloud Storage blob when I download it using the `google-cloud-storage` Python client?

Specifically, my code looks like this:

```
client = Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('my-blob')
with open('some-file', 'w') as f:
  blob.download_to_file(f)
```

And I would like to get the headers (`content-length`, `etag`, etc) sent while downloading the blob.

Note that:

1. Using `blob.size` (and friends) necessitate a call to `blob.reload()`, which makes an HTTP request (and they are not automatically populated once the blob has been downloaded; see comments)
2. Using `requests.get(blob.generate_signed_url())` (or similar) would mean I can't take advantage of the `Client`'s connection pooling

So, without making any additional HTTP requests, is there any way to get the headers when downloading a file from Cloud Storage with the `google-cloud-storage` library?

Comment: If we look here ...https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/93600571c88d31c94d5080af35541d27b0021443/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L1969  we seem to see that calling blob.size() won't make an additional HTTP call but will instead access a local property.  My gut is saying that after a download, the metadata will be present at the caller ready for examination.

Comment: @Kolban that would be very reasonable, but it does not appear to be the case. I've reproduced by running the above code, noticing that the file was correctly downloaded, then observing that `blob.size` is `None` until `blob.reload()` is called. Thanks for the suggestion, though; I've updated the question to include this.

Comment: Hi, have you checked `bucket.get_blob` instead of `bucket.blob`. It automatically downloads the metadata information, maybe that is useful. It does not appear to be any way to access at the same time the metadata information and the content.

Comment: @Juancki Using `bucket.get_blob(…)` is basically `blob = bucket.blob(…); blob.reload()`, which triggers an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve BOTH the object data and the object meta data in one request either through the Python client or any other client.

If we look at the exposed API of Google Cloud Storage (GCS), we find that the API to retrieve the content of an object is documented under Objects -> Get [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get).  This describes a call to:

```
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/object
```

If we look at the parameters available to this request, we find a parameter called `alt` which has two options either:

- `json` (default)
- `media`

At the end of the doc, there is the further comment:

> By default, this responds with an object resource in the response
>   body. If you provide the URL parameter `alt=media`, then it will respond
>   with the object data in the response body.

Reading this carefully, it appears that one can retrieve **either** the metadata **or** the content ... but not both.  Since the REST API is the underlying API against which all other libraries are built, if there is no underlying REST API to retrieve both content and metadata in a single request then there will be no higher level API that achieve such.

Comment: This is true for *all* metadata, but I don't need all the metadata; just the standard HTTP headers returned as part of downloading the object (`Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, etc). These headers are returned any time the object is fetched over HTTP (evidence: they are returned when fetching the object returned by `blob.generate_signed_url()`)

Comment: I would be very surprised if the Python client library exposed the HTTP headers ... the thinking behind a client library is to insulate you from mechanics of calls and the HTTP headers are very much mechanics.   It is also within the realms of possibility that the Google client library doesn't use HTTP but instead uses gRPC in which case there wouldn't be any headers to interrogate.  If you need the HTTP headers, consider using a Python REST client library and calling the documented GCS REST API directly.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, the Python library does not allow for setting the headers and the body at the same time.

This is because the `reload` [function](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/38d8f2b8bdbfdb27dc84b4f3d4ed4998d4cf52e5/storage/google/cloud/storage/notification.py#L291) gets the response object from the `api_request`.

```py
response = client._connection.api_request(
        method="GET", path=self.path, query_params=query_params)
self._set_properties(api_response)
```

However, the functions `download_to_file`, `download_to_filename` and `download_as_string` use another [function](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/38d8f2b8bdbfdb27dc84b4f3d4ed4998d4cf52e5/storage/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L595) `_do_download` that writes directly to a IO Buffer. And does not return the response object.

This later function uses the `Client` pooling you mentioned but it not provisioned to update the blob object properties.